# Decompress LZString in PHP

Tags: php, compression, lzw

I used LZString in my JavaScript to compress some JSON data and then post it to my PHP program. (http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)

I have a binary code so I want decompress in PHP, I use `LZString.php` from this repository : https://github.com/nullpunkt/lz-string-php/blob/master/src/LZString.php

when I use `compress()` method I will get an error, but when I use `decompressFromBase64()` method there is no any error but this funstion return empty string !

how can I decompress LZString in php ?

my data is same as this picture:
[image]

Comment: Why not use a regular request and use HTTP deflate or gzip?

Comment: @AlexanderKerchum because the json data is huge, and post max size is limit, so I should compress my data. How can I use gzip?

Comment: `how can I decompress LZString in php?` what's wrong with "the `decompressFrom*()` functions? `How can I use gzip?` (an unrelated implementation) consult the gzlib documentation.